# How to share my chatbox to other website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, chat

How to share my chatbox to other website without using iframe? 
Can I use javascript? how? anyone can give me some tutorials how to do it?

I would like to have a website like chatwing.com 
They used javascript to put their chatbox to other website.

Here is my code using iframe.

```
<iframe src="xxx.html" style="border:0;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
```

how can i do it without using iframe?

Comment: have them load your javascript, have your script set it up like you would with an iframe

Comment: so it will link the js file? like, <script src='tomysite.com/chat.js'> do i need to give them line of codes like, css and the div?

Comment: you can dynamically build the css and html elements from your javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give people a javascript file to include at the top of their pages.

The javascript would append the chat html (some div) to body and position the chat html appropriately (say at the bottom right...you can do this with jquery for example).

You detect messages entered into the widget via javascript keydown events. On those events you send the messages to your server either via sockets or ajax.

Let me know in the comments if you'd like to walk through this in some more detail.

Comment: any advantages of using this? and some disadvantages?

Comment: We can do a live chat and collaborate on some code here: https://www.sudonow.com/session/52563386c8a39eae15000006 and i can discuss the approach some more

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of php and html. You can make a widget. You can make a script like cometchat, arrowchat. They basically insert/include there javascript file in pages.